# Integrate facebook graph with firebase

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want access to facebook user's original photo size and gender on firebase cloud functions. I was looking graph api but it comes little hard to understand. I can't do that just with firebase as i understand?

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you user has authenticated by Facebook you can get the photoUrl from the Auth Object (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log(userRecord.photoURL);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

If you want to connect to Facebook Graph API then you'll need a pair Firebase account so you can access data outside of Googles network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. UserRecord doesn't contain what i need. (access to big size photo and gender..) So i have to use graph api as i understand.  And thats my question; how can i use graph api in cloud functions?