# Making Facebook graph API calls from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, google-cloud-functions, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have an Android app using Cloud Firestore (Blaze Plan). By calling Firebase Call functions from the Android app I can easily send text from the client and receive answers from the server.

According to the Facebook docs regarding [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens), it is possible to get information from the Facebook Graph API by using an *App Access Token*, without requiring the user to be logged to his Facebook account (if any).

Is it possible to make requests to the Facebook Graph API from a Firebase cloud function (using JS)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make requests to the Facebook graph API from a Firebase function. There are very few examples, but a good one may be [this](https://medium.com/@Astider/how-to-%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87-messenger-chatbot-%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%9A-serverless-%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%A2-google-firebase-908c3eaba67e) (you can find the code [here](https://gist.github.com/mikkipastel/37fa011e3aea7ebb9941fb3dab6f1186)), and this has been explored in other threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638555/integrate-facebook-graph-with-firebase).

Hope you find this helpful.